# Moved a file by mistake with certain time stamp want to restore files with same time satmp

Tags: linux

### By mistake moved some file want them back with same time stamp

```
mv dr * /filespath/to/bkp/
```

is there any way to recover them with same time stamp

Comment: Moving doesn't affect all timestamps. The timestamps for *access* and *modify* are preserved, only the timestamp for *change* gets modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question (and you know the original timestamp) you could move them back, and then use `touch` to give them the old time stamp. Excerpted from `man touch` on GNU/Linux,

> ```
>    -a     change only the access time
>    -m     change only the modification time
>    -t STAMP
>          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
> ```

Comment: This requires knowing the original time stamp, and I guess prudviraj doesn't.

Comment: @scai Then how does he know they aren't the same?

Comment: Probably because now he sees the timestamp of the moving operation somewhere.

Comment: @scai See, I assumed some backup process (or version control system) detected something...

Comment: yep seems this might work for me because i know previous time stamp of my file @scai Thanks for the answer